# I can't redirect output of a python file from a php call

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to execute a python file from php, in python file I have this:

```
import sys
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

nom = sys.argv[1];
print nom

def cmdline(command):
    process = Popen(
        args=command,
        stdout=PIPE,
        shell=True
)
return process.communicate()[0]

cmdline("nmap x.x.x.x -oX sortida.xml")
```

When I execute `python pythonfile.py` works, creates the sortida.xml file, but when y call it from php don't create sortida.xml file, only shows me the print

PHP:

```
    system('python /var/www/core/un.py q');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you call `nmap` directly from `php`?

Comment: I tried this in php: system('nmap x.x.x.x -oX sortida.xml'); and doesn't work :(

Comment: I think I found the solution, finally I used shell_exec and changed the permissions of /var/www to 773 and it works. Is it dangerous?